# How to send apache headers via php like this method ?

Tags: php, apache, header

I've an app that generates several apache raw file like below how can I use all of that as request to php ? as I know we can call them separately like `header("Location: http://www.example.com/");`  but how we can call all of them from one command like this ? (it's just for example)

```
<?php
        header("http://example.com/test.php

            POST test.php HTTP/1.1
            Host: example.com
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
            Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
            Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
            X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
            Referer: http://example.com/test/
            Content-Length: 87
            Cookie: __cfduid=somevalue; 
            Connection: keep-alive
            a=1&b=2");
?>
```

I want to send it completely to my server is it possible ?

Comment: PHP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function sets **response** header which apache returns to clients. Headers in the question are **request** headers sent to apache by clients.

Comment: ok what about just address and referer and cookies and params in one command ?

Comment: You cannot set referer or make browser submit a POST request via headers. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract it from a text and use the `header()` method after all... Sort of like this:

```
<?php
$txt = "http://example.com/test.php
POST test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://example.com/test/
Content-Length: 87
Cookie: __cfduid=somevalue;
Connection: keep-alive
a=1&b=2";

array_map("header", explode("\n", $txt));
```

So essentially, every new line creates an entry in an array. `array_map()` traverses the array and for every item in the array, the `header()` function is invoked with the item in the array as sole argument.

Answer (score 1):

PHP header function sets **response** header which apache returns to clients. Headers in the question are **request** headers sent to apache by clients.

From the [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html):

> 6.2 Response Header Fields
>
> The response-header fields allow the server to pass additional
>      information about the response which cannot be placed in the Status-
>      Line. These header fields give information about the server and about
>      further access to the resource identified by the Request-URI.
>
> ```
>    response-header = Accept-Ranges           ; Section 14.5
>                    | Age                     ; Section 14.6
>                    | ETag                    ; Section 14.19
>                    | Location                ; Section 14.30
>                    | Proxy-Authenticate      ; Section 14.33
>                    | Retry-After             ; Section 14.37
>                    | Server                  ; Section 14.38
>                    | Vary                    ; Section 14.44
>                    | WWW-Authenticate        ; Section 14.47
> ```
>
> Response-header field names can be extended reliably only in
>      combination with a change in the protocol version. However, new or
>      experimental header fields MAY be given the semantics of response-
>      header fields if all parties in the communication recognize them to
>      be response-header fields. Unrecognized header fields are treated as
>      entity-header fields.

Other RFCs [extend this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields), but you cannot set referrer, or make browser to submit another POST request via headers.

Comment: So in this case with apache header we can just call one url without any referer ? if yes, how we can call that ?

Comment: I believe you are falling into [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest to delete the question and ask the real one - what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can send multiple headers one by one using the optional "replace" argument and setting it to false. So, for example, you could send

```
header("http://example.com/test.php");
header("POST test.php HTTP/1.1",false);
```

and so on. This would append to the original header.

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I know that ,as I told in my question, but it's about 1000 files ! and I want to send all in one command

Comment: The replace is used to replace a header you have already set using the `header()` function... It is not to reset different header types....